# How can I write notes on row-operations of a matrix?

Tags: tex

I can write only one using square brackets like this:

[image]

but I want to add more brackets like that.How can I do that?

Comment: This would be better at https://tex.stackexchange.com which is dedicated to TeX.

Comment: have you tried using `\substack`?

Comment: @IsaacDj Nope.I'm actually a beginner and so I don't know \substack

Comment: look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009782/latex-stack-three-lines-in-math-mode

Comment: @IsaacDj thanks for providing me with that link! The answer to that question solved my problem.

Comment: Great, good luck

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LaTeX: stack three lines in math mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009782/latex-stack-three-lines-in-math-mode)